# Sinatra - Saving Twilio SMS to CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, sinatra, twilio

I have a very simple Sinatra app that allows me to receive SMS messages through my Twilio number and will print them to the same terminal session that the app is running on. I would like to save these messages to a local .csv file. Adding `CSV.open()` to the app throws some errors.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'csv'

post '/receive_sms' do
    @body   = params["Body"].to_s
    @sid    = params["MessageSid"].to_s
    @sender = params["From"].delete('+').to_i
    content_type 'text/xml'

    puts @body
    puts @sender
    puts @sid
    CSV.open("/home/ubuntu/Twilio_SMS/smsLog.csv", "a") do |csv|
      csv << [@sender, @body, @sid]
    end
end
```

This gives me the following errors:

```
ERROR IOError: closed stream
        /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:16:in `close'
        /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:117:in `ensure in service'
        /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:117:in `service'
        /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
        /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
        /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have tried moving the CSV call outside of the post method, but this only writes `, ,` to the file every time I start the applicaiton.

What is the proper way to save this informaiton to the CSV file and make sure that every message is added even if they are recieved in rapid succession?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a valid return value to the method.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'csv'

post '/receive_sms' do
    @body   = params["Body"].to_s
    @sid    = params["MessageSid"].to_s
    @sender = params["From"].delete('+').to_i
    content_type 'text/xml'

    puts @body
    puts @sender
    puts @sid
    CSV.open("/home/ubuntu/Twilio_SMS/smsLog.csv", "a") do |csv|
      csv << [@sender, @body, @sid]
    end

    'done'
end
```

Because 'CSV.open' was the last method you ran, Sinatra tried to read from it to generate an HTTP reply - and invoked an `IOError` from trying to read from a closed stream.